# how to handle page in MVC? page object showing null value how can I use this statement in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

I have two interfaces in my asp.net(C#) application(`IAppNavigation`,`IViewDimensions`) , I am converting the asp.net application into asp.net MVC4(razor).

The below code is in some class file

```
Page Page = null;
if (Page == null)
{
    Page = HttpContext.Current.Handler as Page;
}

IViewDimensions dims = ((IAppNavigation)Page).GetCurrentDimensions();
```

How to handle page in MVC? page object showing null value how can I use this statement in MVC4?

Please find the below the listed two interfaces.

```
public interface IAppNavigation
    {
       IViewDimensions GetCurrentDimensions();  
    }

public interface IViewDimensions
    {
        DimensionDetail this[string dimensionName]
        {
            get;
        }

        DimensionDetail[] Dimensions
        {
            get;
        }

        IViewDimensions Clone();

        void SetDimension( string dimensionName, string memberName );

        List<int> GetGeoIds(string geo);
    }
```

Comment: Could you check where "Page" is being used...

Comment: Page Class : Represents an .aspx file, also known as a Web Forms page, requested from a server that hosts an ASP.NET Web application.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page(v=vs.110).aspx In mvc there is a views not .aspx files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply J-D. its very huge application and somany other places using the same page object. If you can suggest  any other alternate for this page object it will helpful to me.

Comment: I suppose it's hard to migrate your logic with this classes as it is to MVC. As @J-D said there is no such thing as page in MVC but you have ViewModels and Strongly typed Views. So you should think of your problems in context of MVC pipeline.